# Tooltips in Joomla containing HTML

Tags: javascript, joomla, tooltip

I created a component using [Component Creator](http://www.component-creator.com/) for Joomla 3.X

The problem is that on the site the tooltips show html code. For example:

```
<strong>Title</strong><br/>Description
```

Instead, on the administrator they are displayed properly:

> **Title**
>
> Description

I was reviewing the documentation [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_tooltips_to_your_Joomla!_website) and [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage), and it seems that it is possible to define the output format when calling the tooltip function but there are no calls inside the component to that function. The only call I see is `JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');` at the begining of the view file and don't know how to specify the output format.

The site is in this URL:

```
http://50.87.185.99/colombianadederecho_blank/index.php/administradores-ph/registrarse
```

**Added:**

It seems like the code is called when building the label for each field:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('document'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('document'); ?></div>
</div>
```

And it is stored in the title attribute:

```
title="&lt;strong&gt;Title&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Description"
```

So, I think the problem is in the Javascript function, maybe using a .text() jQuery function instead of a .html().

Inspecting the source code I found this, but don't understand why it is not working properly:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
            $$('.hasTip').each(function(el) {
                var title = el.get('title');
                if (title) {
                    var parts = title.split('::', 2);
                    el.store('tip:title', parts[0]);
                    el.store('tip:text', parts[1]);
                }
            });
            var JTooltips = new Tips($$('.hasTip'), {"maxTitleChars": 50,"fixed": false});
        });

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
});
```

**Solution:**
As @ilias found it was a problem between libraries. I had to disable the bootstrap call in the header using this [plugin](http://digitaldisseny.com/en/joomla-extensions/disable-mootools-joomla-per-itemid-solve-jquery-conflicts) and call it from the end of the body:

```
<script src="/site/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the code that Component Creator produces, however I assume that the tooltips are like in the administrator views. If this is the case you should check for something like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JHtml::tooltipText('JSEARCH_FILTER_SUBMIT'); ?>"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
```

and enclose the contents of `JHtml::tootlipText()` in `strip_tags()`.

Otherwise try to find the line `<strong>Title</strong><br/>Description` where the tags are shown and enclose it in `strip_tags()`. For example you might have something that looks like:

```
echo $this->escape($item->description);
```

that should be turned into:

```
echo $this->escape(strip_tags($item->description));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I need. The idea is to keep the format using the html tags. In addition, where the code is called it includes many other information and I should face other problems. I just added how the code looks where it is called.

Comment: I see, have you tried `JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');` instead? Or since the title is as you show it html escaped, `title="&lt;strong&gt;Title&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Description"` maybe something changes the tags because they should be `<strong>Title</strong><br/>Description` so that the tags are interpreted and if this is the case its not a text() vs html() issue. Try and tell me how it goes.

Comment: It has to be something else... I tried even removing the line but nothing happens. It is like the code was taken from other place or a sort of cache was enabled because I can't even disable the tooltips. The tags are `<strong>Title</strong><br/>Description` in the source code but when I copied them from Chrome it changed them to `&lt;strong&gt;Title&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Description`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I made it work with the bootstrap tooltips. There is a conflict between JQuery/Jquerynoconflict/Bootstap and Mootools for instance the way I did it for testing was by adding the following at the **end** of your html code: `<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$('.hasTooltip').tooltip({html:true});</script>
</body></html>` However there are issues with the css but you can probably override the generated css.

Comment: You're right. The problem is with bootstrap. I disabled all the scripts for a moment using this plugin http://digitaldisseny.com/en/joomla-extensions/disable-mootools-joomla-per-itemid-solve-jquery-conflicts and tested different combinations. What is needed is to call the bootstrap.min.js as the last script. No needs to call jQuery again or call the .tooltip function. Thank you very much.

Comment: Going farther I found the problem is between jQuery UI and Bootstrap. Putting Bootstrap just after jQuery UI shows those yellow tooltips with the correct format. Putting it just before, shows those gray tooltips with the tags.